# Reading value from JSON array in Node.js during Get request

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I need to pull the `Indication` value from the following array

```
 {
    "records": [{
        "id": "recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo",
        "fields": {
            "DrugName": "azatadine",
            "nameapi": ["recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"],
            "Indication": "For the relief of the symptoms of upper respiratory mucosal congestion in perennial and allergic rhinitis, and for the relief of nasal congestion and eustachian t.b. congestion.",
            "lookup": ["azatadine"],
            "drugID": "recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"
        },
        "createdTime": "2018-11-09T19:38:24.000Z"
    }]
 }
```

When I try to do `response.records.fields[0]["Indication"]` I get undefined.

Here is my full code:

```
function httpGet() {

return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {

var options = {

host: 'api.airtable.com',

port: 443,

path: '/v0/appYqfJ3Rt2F0sRGn/Database?filterByFormula=(DrugName=%27azatadine%27)',

method: 'GET',

headers: {

Authorization: 'Bearer key123456789'

}

};

const request = https.request(options, (response) => {

response.setEncoding('utf8');

let returnData = '';

response.on('data', (chunk) => {

returnData += chunk;

});

response.on('end', () => {

resolve(returnData);

});

response.on('error', (error) => {

reject(error);

});

});

request.end();

}));

}



const UserReplyIntent_Handler = {

canHandle(handlerInput) {

const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

return request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'UserReplyIntent' ;

},

async handle(handlerInput) {

const response = await httpGet();

console.log(response);

return handlerInput.responseBuilder

.speak("Okay. Here we go" + response.records[0].fields.Indication)

.reprompt("say again")

.getResponse();

},

};
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

it should be  `response.records[0].fields.Indication`

Comment: Didn't work. I'm still getting Error handled: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: This is my full line:  .speak("this drug is called" + response.records.[0].fields.Indication )

Comment: If I do     .speak("Okay. Here we go" + response)
 it spits out the entire thing... 

Okay. Here we go {"records":[{"id":"recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo","fields":{"DrugName":"azatadine","nameapi":["recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"],"Indication":"For the relief of the symptoms of upper respiratory mucosal congestion in perennial and allergic rhinitis, and for the relief of nasal congestion and eustachian t.b. congestion.","lookup":["azatadine"],"drugID":"recBgV3VDiJeMkcwo"},"createdTime":"2018-11-09T19:38:24.000Z"}]}

Comment: it should not be `response.records.[0].fields.Indication` 
it shoud be `response.records[0].fields.Indication`

Comment: `records` is an array. you need access the first element by `records[0]`

Comment: Still not working. I tried response.records[0].fields.Indication and it returns object Object.

Comment: Try this `JSON.stringify(res.records[0].fields.Indication)` if it does not work can you give me the output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196756/discussion-between-notyourguru-and-nafis-islam).

Answer (score 0):

Fields doesn't look like an array. Try `response.records.fields.Indication`

Comment: Didn't work. I'm getting ````Error handled: Cannot read property '0' of undefined````

Answer (score 0):

Show console.log(response) output. Looks like that you made a mistake in getting a response

Comment: The only thing I'm getting back in console is this: Error handled: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I've updated my question with my code. Thanks for your help